# Button appearing below and not to the right

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(30, 21, 120);
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.package {
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(37, 110, 194);
}

p.package {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="package">
    <div nowrap>
      <p>Recommended Package</p>
      <button value="Purchase">Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to make a box that text in it and I am trying to put a button to the right of the text. However, whenever I make the button float to the right or nest divs, the button ends up being under the text, or the entire box breaks. I also used display: inline on divs (which broke the box). I want the button to look like this:

[image]

However, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure `nowrap` doesn't apply to anything other than table cells

Comment: @YaakovAinspan You're right. When I came across this problem, I (of course) started searching around and found a post about "nowrap." Didn't realise it was meant to table cells only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: inline;` to the `<p>`. The default is block, which means that the `<p>` will extend across the whole width of the screen. Setting it to inline will mean that it just takes up how much space it needs.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(30, 21, 120);
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
}

.package {
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(37, 110, 194);
}

p.package {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="package">
    <div nowrap>
      <p>Recommended Package</p>
      <button value="Purchase">Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add display: inline-block and vertical-align:middle to p tag